# Haskell :improve list union

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to create a union function for two images (created using lists of type string.) I have started by creating a unionList function that combines two lists.

```
unionList :: String -> String -> String  
unionList xs ys =  xs ++ foldl (flip delete) ys xs
```

This works but not how i want it too.
I want it to work like:

```
input = unionList [’ ’,’ ’,’X’,’X’,’ ’] [’X’,’ ’,’X’,’ ’,’X’] 
output = "X XXX"
```

any ideas on how it's done to achieve this.

EDIT: I'm ultimately trying to create a union of two images.

```
image 1 = ["  XX  ",     image 2 = ["XX XX",         type Img = [String]
           " X  X ",                "  X  ",
           "  XX  "]                "XX XX"]
```

^
*examples*

```
Input = (imgUnion (image 1) (image 2))
```

should give me the union of the two images.
imgUnion defined as

```
imgUnion :: Img -> Img -> Img
```

Comment: Start with a solution that only works on lists of length 1 and uses pattern matching (on lists and `Char` literals). Google "pattern matching haskell" if you don't understand what I mean. Then add more cases (to match the empty list) and a recursive call to `unionList` to support lists of arbitrary length.

Comment: Look at `zipWith`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs - I looked into zipWith and will use it for the image union. but i want to get the unionList function to work as defined above first and use it with zipWith.

Comment: `unionList` is the function that I am suggesting you use `zipWith` for. The function as defined above is wrong, and I don't know how to make it work, since it is wrong.

Comment: If you use prelude functions I would suggest at least looking at their implementation so that you learn something from this exercise

Comment: @ReinHenrichs - I'm new to Haskell so feel free to completely ignore how I've done it and go about it how you would do it.

Comment: Try doing it with `zipWith`. I don't want to just give you the answer because this is homework.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs - its not homework. i'm learning Haskell in my spare time  so i asked for some material that will help me practice from my professor. Though I understand where your coming from.

Comment: Your example looks more like "element-wise OR", not a UNION (with the lists being treated like sets).

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to do this, but I had some fun trying out a couple of methods.

Pattern matching on list head item:

```hs
unionList1 :: String -> String -> String
unionList1 ('X':xs) ( _ :ys) = 'X' : unionList1 xs ys
unionList1 ( _ :xs) ('X':ys) = 'X' : unionList1 xs ys
unionList1 ( _ :xs) ( _ :ys) = ' ' : unionList1 xs ys
unionList1     _        _    = []
```

Guards!

```hs
unionList2 :: String -> String -> String
unionList2 (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == ' '   = y : rest
  | y == ' '   = x : rest
  | otherwise  = x : rest
  where rest   = unionList2 xs ys
unionList2 _ _ = []
```

And a solution as proposed with `zipWith`:

```hs
unionList3 :: String -> String -> String
unionList3 = zipWith (\x y -> if x /= ' ' then x else y)
```

You can then use one of these union functions on the image:

```hs
imgUnion :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
imgUnion = zipWith unionList3

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let img1 = ["  XX  ",
                " X  X ",
                "  XX  "]
        img2 = ["XX XX",
                "  X  ",
                "XX XX"]

    mapM_ putStrLn (imgUnion img1 img2)
```

Gives as output:

```hs
XXXXX
 XX X
XXXXX
```

Comment: It is for the UnionList function. How will i include this for the image union function.  (edit in question)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your edited question, is this what you're looking for?